# jmeter - unable to record on the c4c https page

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

I am using **Jmeter 2.13** in proxy mode to record the **c4c CRM cloud application.**

it records login page perfectly. once i land into home page,following things are observed and unable to record.

1. I try click on the link- but could not open the link during recording, but without recording it is woring fine.
2. There is a NEW button during normal browsing, but during recording mode NEW button is not displayed.

please suggest me on this. and this is completely new to me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try in Recorder switching Implementation to Java and see if it helps.

Otherwise did you accept the certificate generated by JMeter ?